# Get outlook calendar events without OAuth

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, calendar

I have logged in to the outlook account, and also the account is same for SharePoint. I need to capture all the outlook calendar events and show it up in SharePoint. I have already logged in to the outlook, so I don't want to authenticate again using OAuth. Is there anyway to get all the calendar events for logged user without authenticate again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open authentication is there to let the user choose what user scopes to be allowed for your application. What if a user doesn't want to share his/her calendar events to your application. 
If you want to reduce steps you can grant all privileges during the first login but your application won't be able to retrieve information from a user scope, say calendars, without granting access.